# Aligning text next to a button with materialize CSS

Tags: html, css, alignment, materialize

I have a button and some text next to it. I'd like to match the text's vertical alignment with the button's. Here's what I have now:

[image]

Basically, I'd like the `or Sign Up` text to go a bit higher. I'm using MaterializeCSS as well. Here's the code I have for this:

**HTML**

```
<div class="center">
  <button class="btn waves-effect waves-green green darken-1">Sign In</button>
  <span class="alternate-option">or <a href="#">Sign Up</a></span>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.alternate-option {
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

I have tried using `padding-bottom` as well as `margin-bottom`.

Comment: ... where is the CSS for the button? How can we know the height etc?

Comment: I think you will need to provide a bit more code to enable us to replicate the image. As long as they are `inline` or `inline-block` adding `vertical-align: middle;` to the `button` and `span` will probably work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use:

```
.alternate-option {
  margin-left: 20px;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  position: relative;
  top:-5px;
}
```

Also look at: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp

Answer (score 3):

This is caused by MaterializeCSS's button style :

```
margin-bottom: 15px;
```

An alternate solution to Mousa Dirksz's [span repositionning](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28990709/4031358) would be to 
**remove** the button's default margin :

**HTML**

```
<div class="center">
    <div class="alternate-option">
        <button class="btn waves-effect waves-green green darken-1">Sign In</button>
        <span>or <a href="#">Sign Up</a></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.alternate-option button {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}    

.alternate-option span {
    margin-left: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For anyone looking to center a button and a link it's possible to use the following snippet:

```html
<div class="valign-wrapper">
  <button class="btn waves-effect waves-green green darken-1">Sign In</button>
  <span class="alternate-option">or <a href="#">Sign Up</a></span>
</div>
```

```
.alternate-option {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

It's important to note that using Materialize **valign-wrapper** class will vertically align children elements but it will remove the spacing between them that's why we need to add a **margin-left** on the span children.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the full CSS, I suspect that you need to vertically align the button and span..such as:

```
button, span {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this suggestion
Use absolute positioning

---

CSS:

```
.alternate-option {
            position:absolute;
            left:numeric value*(adjust according screen size)*
            top:numeric value*(adjust according screen size)*
    }
```